# How do I create a Spring Boot endpoint that can accept multiple different types as RequestBody?

Tags: spring-boot

I have 2 messages like this...

```
{
  "type":"MessageString",
  "message": {
    "value":"..."
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "type":"MessageObject",
  "message": {
    "value": { ... }
  }
}
```

Then I have a Spring Boot endpoint like...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("...")
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping(
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public String processMessage(
            @RequestBody (?) wrapper
    ){
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to know what kind of classes I can use to accept both types? I had it working like this....

```
class MessageWrapper<T extends MessageType>{
  private T message; 
}
```

But then I still have to declare the type in the response body like...

```
@RequestBody MessageWrapper<Object> wrapper
```

or

```
@RequestBody MessageWrapper<String> wrapper
```

So this wouldn't work because I can't have 2 response bodies.

I am trying to keep this as simple as possible so I would like to avoid making the @RequestBody a string then parsing it inside the controller.

Comment: serialize and deserialize into generics, requires often a custom serializers och jackson annotations. If you want to keep things simple, you dont serialize/deserialize into generics. If you want to keep things even simpler, you define your type with a enum, and then switch on the enum and create your class. It will probably be a lot simpler.

Comment: Right but all of this would require the request body to just be a string until I serialize it in the service or somewhere right?